# "\No": "Undefined control sequence" in TeXStudio (TeXLive)

Tags: miktex, texlive, texstudio, texworks

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@title ->Home work \\ Economics \No 
                           ~2
l.16 \maketitle
```

Today, I tried to change my text-editor from TeXworks to TeXStudio (and MiKTeX to TeXLive also) and run there (in TeXStudio, which connected with packages of TeXLive) my homework. So, as you see above, the problem is connected with the "\No~2".

TeXworks worked it out fine and put the sign, but TeXStudio did not. And when I remove "\No", undoubtedly, TeXStudio works okay too.

Is there any opportunity to teach TeXStudio a Number sign (\No) in \maketitle? In the rest of the text it does not works too.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{array}
```

---

```
\title{Home work \\ Economics \No~2}

\author{MY name}

\date{12 may 2014}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\textbf{\large Task 1}

Some stuff

\end{document}
```

P.S.: when I put "\No~2" in some part of the text (not in title information) it does not work too. I think, that I have to say that this is the russian symbol (№) of a number. The sign is slightly differ from the English one (No. or #).

I need this:
[image: \No~2 by texworks in \maketitle]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Texworks and texstudio are merely editors, if you didn't change the distribution (TeX Live) iinbetween they should both give the same results.

Comment: Thanks, Johannes_B.
Yes, sorry, I edited my question.
Also, I have changed MiKTeX to TeXLive. However, the texworks, which is in TeXLive-package too has no trouble with "\No"

Comment: Your example doesn't work because `\No` is not defined. You need to define it, or load a package that defines it.

Comment: Thanks @IanThompson. I have not understood why texworks (either MikTeX's or TeXLive's) put the \No without any definition, but whereas in contrast TeXStudio has a trouble to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you were compiling exactly the same document?

Comment: The editor you use texworks, texstudio, notepad, ... makes no difference. If you get a different behaviour then TeX has loaded different files. Perhaps the babel russian package has changed, the package version numbers will be printed in the log file so you can compare.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you. However, TeXStudio (which is using TeXLive stuff) do not cope with the "No~2" in the title information, but, TeXworks (which using MiKTeX's or TeXlive's stuff) do.

Comment: @IanThompson, actually, I tried "\No~2" in different part of the text (TeXStudio) and it did not work anywhere, not only in \maketitle. This is the russian symbol of a number. The sign is slightly differ from the English one.

Comment: By the way, `#` is the American English sign. It doesn't have the same meaning in British English, at least. I'm not sure if `No.` is recognised in American English - at least it is not standard at all as it is in British English.

Comment: You need to load `textcomp` and use `\textnumero` or define `\No` to produce `\textnumero`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol is provided by `textcomp` which defines `\textnumero` but you can create `\No` as a new command to produce the same symbol:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand*{\No}{\textnumero}

\title{Home work\\Economics \No~2}

\author{MY name}

\date{12 may 2014}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Task 1}% use semantic markup

Some stuff

\end{document}
```

Incidentally, this symbol also means 'number' in British English but is maybe a little old fashioned and so tends not to be used. (I guess because `No.` probably got used when typewriters were unable to produce specialised symbols but I'm not sure.)

[image: Number symbol]

Comment: Thank you. I am inclined to believe that this answer is the most laconic in comparison to others and also contains advise (for me) regarding \section* (brilliant idea!). To be honest, I have not tried solution of cfr's (about "\No"), because I returned back from TeXLive to MiKTeX and embeded TeXStudio in MiKTeX and TeXStudio started to work fine on MiKTeX stuff so no need to do it.

Comment: @VladimirYashin Does your document use different fonts in that case? I'm curious because I noticed that TeX Live used not type1 but metafont fonts when I ran your code and Bernard's answer suggests that might well make a difference.

Comment: sorry, may be I do not quite understand, but whatever, I use the default font (CMU Serif) it is fully satisfied me, esp. with the "cm-super"-package.

Answer (score 2):

The `russian` option of babel defines a `\No` macro for cyrillic numero sign (Unicode "2116). You can get it using the `Latin Modern` font and loading `fontenc` with `T2A, TS1, T1` option.

You also obtain it with `XeLaTeX`,  loading the `fontspec` and `polyglossia` packages. Then you have to define the`\No` command.

Here is a code that can work both ways (commenting and uncommenting the relevant parts):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T2A, TS1,T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\providecommand\No{\char"2116}%{№}%

\title{Home work \\ Economics \No ~2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

And the results of both ways, the XeLaTeX way with Minion Pro:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `may` supposed to print like that? Note that I am by no means asserting that it is not. I'm just curious as I'm essentially wholly ignorant of what to expect with `russian` and it looks confusingly like a partially mirrored `mar` to my ignorant eyes.

Comment: Also, I can't get your commented code to work - it complains `\No` is undefined. Moreover `russian.ldf`, at least, does not appear to define any such command.

Comment: @cfr: As to `may`, I don't know: as you can see, the code doesn't contain any reference to `\date` and I don't speak Russian, so I have no idea whether it looks weird or not. I can't remember where I read a `\No` command did exist with the russian option of LaTeX, but it struck me because there does exist such a command in  `frenchb`, so I simply decided to test it… and it worked on my system! That's all I can say. Perhaps because I use MiKTeX, and latest babel for MiKTeX is `3.8 m`?

Comment: It does not work in TeX Live. (This is the updated-up-to-the-freeze 2013 version.) My babel is 3.9k so perhaps that's the difference?

Comment: Yes, I wonder. Strangely, if I type `\newcommand\No{…}`, I have  the `command already defined` error message with the russian option of babel, and no message without this option.

Comment: I thought you said babel-russian defined it in your version? (So it is not strange at all in that case though maybe strange that babel-russian defines it?)

Comment: That's what I meant: it's strange it has disappeared from one version to the next. Or maybe it introduced a conflict between frenchb and russian (the french \No is typeset with usual characters, while the russian uses \textnumero ie U2116).

Comment: Maybe but several other languages define it incompatibly so I don't know why Russian and French should be especially problematic.

Comment: @Bernard, date looks as it should look, that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian said, you have not defined a macro `\No` in the document class or any loaded package, at least in your TeX Live distribution, so any editor will produce the same error (also TeXworks).

But is is simple define `\No` in your preamble as you want. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\newcommand\No{N.\textsuperscript{o}}
\title{Home work \\ Economics   \No ~2}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Because you are using `babel` that in russian use the shorthand `"`, you can also define a new shorthand for ordinals. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\defineshorthand{"o}{$.\!$º}
\begin{document}
\title{Home work\\Economics N"o~2}
\maketitle
N"o $\neq$ N.\textsuperscript{o}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you want to use the shorthand in the `\title`, it must be in the body of the document, before of `\maketitle`, but not in the preamble.

BTW, as most fonts use a not underlined `\textordmasculine` symbol, very similar to the degree symbol, if you want it underlined without change the font, you can define you macro/shorthand to write some like:

```
N$\!$.$\!$\textsuperscript{\tiny\underline{o}}
```